# Connecting Mulesoft to Kafka hosted at Heroku

Tags: heroku, apache-kafka, mulesoft, mule4

community!

I'm trying to connect my Mulesoft application to a Kafka Server that is hosted at Heroku. Anypoint Studio 7 (Mule 4) have a Kafka connector that has a few options to connect (Basic, Kerberos, Kerberos SSL and SSL):

[image: Kafka Connector's Setup]

According to Heroku's docs it "support" SSL but does not mention that is required. Can anyone confirm?

Heroku documentation that I saw [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/kafka-on-heroku]

When I set up an app at Heroku, add the Kafka AddOn, create the topic, I get the bootstrap server(s) from running the command `heroku config:get KAFKA_URL`  If I try to to abasic test I get the following error:

[image]

The error states `org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: invalid connection!
  org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: invalid connection!
  Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.`

what I'm trying to build is a PoC with 2 flows... one that produces a message to a Topic and the other flow to consume from it.

[image]

Any help on how to set up the connector and the Heroku environment will be most welcome

---

UPDATE:

I found that when you create the app at Heroku and include the KAFKA addon, you get the following variables:

**KAFKA_URL**: A comma-separated list of SSL URLs to the Kafka brokers making up the cluster. Example:

> kafka+ssl://ec2-3-*****-100.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9096,kafka+ssl://ec2-3-******-127.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9096

**KAFKA_TRUSTED_CERT:** The brokers’ SSL certificate (in PEM format), to check that you’re connecting to the right servers. Example:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDfzCCAmegAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAyMTAwLgYDVQQDDCdjYS1l
>   ZjQwOWUzNy00NjhhLTRiMGEtOGVkOC0wZWYxMmRhYjkyZWEwHhcNMTkxMjEyMTUx
>   NzU5WhcNMjkxMjEyMTUxNzU5WjAyMTAwLgYDVQQDDCdjYS1lZjQwOWUzNy00Njhh

**KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT:** The required client certificate (in PEM format) to authenticate clients against the broker. Example:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDQzCCAiugAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAyMTAwLgYDVQQDDCdjYS1l
>   ZjQwOWUzNy00NjhhLTRiMGEtOGVkOC0wZWYxMmRhYjkyZWEwHhcNMjAwMTE1MTU1
>   MjU2WhcNMzAwMTE1MTU1MjU2WjAZMRcwFQYDVQQDDA51NnZtYWVzM2cwZnMyZjCC

**KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT_KEY:** The required client certificate key (in PEM format) to authenticate clients against the broker.
Kafka clusters require authenticating using the provided client certificate. Any requests not using the client certificate will be denied. Example:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAmmu+j9DulVnqwIOt02++6Ehw9Mg7KaocdIQjODVtVipC5AyK
>   iaHsdNVh9bgJQAJSfstIV/6O1mCLmjUS/YmyIEEgmBvATFxcldPGBGcpPVSV2R3Q

I assume that I need to "transform" those into the KeyStore and TrustStore for the Connector SSL config.. can anyone confirm? since for what I see from the docs, SSL is required

---

Another Update:

I downloaded the certificates I describe above and using the tool "Key explorer" I created a keystore.jks and imported the KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT and KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT_KEY into it and then I created a truststore.jsk and imported the file KAFKA_TRUSTED_CERT there. on both cases I set a basic password ... was looking good but I get an error:

```
org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: invalid connection!
  org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: invalid connection!
  Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1521)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:528)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1197)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1165)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeWrap(SslTransportLayer.java:448)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:313)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:547)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:540)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1709)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:318)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:970)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:967)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1459)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:402)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:340)
    ... 7 more
  Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching ec2-3-220-121-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com found
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:231)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:96)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:252)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1626)
    ... 16 more
```

Could be related to the line Caused by:

> java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching
>   ec2-3-220-121-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com found

Comment: By the team I was working on this... a colleague crack it up: https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/connectivity-dev/how-to-connect-to-apache-kafka-on-heroku

Answer (score 1):

### I got it to work.

create the JKS files using these commands (require HEROKU CLI)

```
client_key=`heroku config:get KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT_KEY --app <SET_HEROKU_APP_NAME_HERE>`
client_cert=`heroku config:get KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT --app <SET_HEROKU_APP_NAME_HERE>`
trusted_cert=`heroku config:get KAFKA_TRUSTED_CERT --app <SET_HEROKU_APP_NAME_HERE>`
# Write config vars to files.
echo "$client_key" >> keystore.pem
echo -n "$client_cert" >> keystore.pem
echo -n "$trusted_cert" > truststore.pem
# Set passwords
TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=<SET_PASSWORD_HERE>
KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=<SET_PASSWORD_HERE>
echo $TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD
echo $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
# Import cert.
keytool -importcert -file truststore.pem -keystore kafka.client.truststore.jks -deststorepass $TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD -noprompt
# Create PKCS12 file.
openssl pkcs12 -export -in keystore.pem -out keystore.pkcs12 -password pass:$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
# Create jks files.
keytool -importkeystore -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
    -destkeystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -deststorepass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD \
    -srckeystore keystore.pkcs12 -srcstorepass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
```

---

Then config the connector with the SSL option and add the following INLINE:

[image]